# how to use cocoa touch framework with xib

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I would like to develop cocoa touch framework with xib.
I am trying to include xib and class in framework.
Then I wrote the following code in my framework,

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    @IBOutlet public weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet public weak var itemIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    public weak var delegate: NoImageDelegate?

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        //  xib読み込み
        let strBundleId = "jp.co.hogehoge.libraly"
        let bundle = NSBundle(identifier: strBundleId)
        let view = bundle?.loadNibNamed("CustomImageView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        addSubview(view)

        // 表示初期化
        _initView()
    }
    ...
}  
....
....
```

And My app loads CustomImageView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var workImageView: CustomImageView!
```

then i got error which is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` from my app.

CustomImageView is included by my framework.

How do i resolve?